# How to unnest tibbles within a tibble?

Tags: r

I have a tibble with some variables being other tibbles made of doubles. All the tibbles nested within the main tibble have the same number of rows of the main tibble.

I want to unnest all the nested tibbles to get one tibble with each variable being a vector.

`%>% unnest()` does not work.

Try to unnest this `data`

```
data <- tibble(col1 = 1:5, col2 = data.frame(col3 = 1:5, col4 = 5:9))
```

Notice that I have to unnest all the variables of `data`.

Comment: Please show a small reprodcuible example

Comment: This examples works `dat <- tibble(col1 = 1:5, col2 = list(tibble(col2 = 1:4, col3 = 5:8))); dat %>% unnest(col2)#
# A tibble: 20 × 3`

Comment: Because in your example, is not a tibble within a tibble. These are tibbles within a list within a tibble; hence unnest() works.

Try this code, which is mutuate from yours:
`dat <- tibble(col1 = 1:5, col2 = data.frame(col3 = 1:5, col4 = 5:9))`

I need a command like unnest() but for tibbles/df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to have regular columns, try with `do.call` and `data.frame`

```
out <-  do.call(data.frame, data)
names(out)[-1] <- names(data$col2)
```

-output

```
> out
  col1 col3 col4
1    1    1    5
2    2    2    6
3    3    3    7
4    4    4    8
5    5    5    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a neat solution in dplyr

```
data %>% bind_cols(.$col2) %>% select(-col2)

# A tibble: 5 × 3
   col1  col3  col4
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     5
2     2     2     6
3     3     3     7
4     4     4     8
5     5     5     9
```